# Looping through pages but no results on pages after 1

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have what I think is a cache or cookie problem. When I run my code on one page (any page), it will give me the results on that page (about 40 listings). When I iterate from range (1,4) for example, to get the first 3 pages, the first page gives 40 listings, but I get 0 results for pages 2, 3, 4. If I run my code on page 2 only, it will give me 40 listings. I've tried implementing a retry method and to retry the link 10 times and it didn't work. I've also tried rotating user agents in my header to use a different browser on each page, but still not working.

My code is below, I'd appreciate any insight here.

```
import requests, pandas, random
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry

user_agent_list = [
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1.1 Safari/605.1.15',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0',
  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36',
]

domain = "https://www.kijiji.ca"
base_url = ("https://www.kijiji.ca/b-cars-trucks/ontario/used/")
listCars = []  #empty list for final dictionaries

#100 pages constitutes ~17 hour cycles - to check once per 24h
for x in range(2,4):

    user_agent = random.choice(user_agent_list)
    getHeader = {'User-Agent': user_agent}
    new_url = base_url + f"page-{x}" + "/c174l9004a49"
    # r = session.get(new_url)
    try:
        r = requests.get(new_url, timeout=10, headers = getHeader)
        print("")
        print("Https Request Success: FULL PAGE {}:  {}".format(x, new_url))
        print("")
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
        print("")
        print("ERROR: Can't Get Page {}".format(x))
        print("")
        continue
    page = r.content 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

    #list of every ad on page which should be looped through
    rows = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "regular-ad"})
    print("{} Results on Page {}.".format(len(rows), x))


    #looping through each single ad on index page
    for row in rows:
        carDictionary = {}
        ad_id = row.get("data-listing-id")
        ad_url = domain + row.get("data-vip-url")
        if "kijijiautos.ca" in ad_url:
            print("Skipped Invalid URL Ad")
            continue
        carDictionary["Ad ID"] = ad_id
        carDictionary["Ad URL"] = ad_url

        #getting price value
        carPriceRaw = row.find("div", {"class": "price"}).text.replace("\n", "").replace(" ","")
        try:
            if carPriceRaw == "Please Contact":
                carPrice = None
            elif carPriceRaw == "PleaseContact":
                carPrice = None
            else:
                carPrice = int(float(row.find("div", {"class": "price"}).text.replace("\n", "").replace(" ","").replace('$', '').replace(',', '')))
            carDictionary["Price"] = carPrice
        except (ValueError):
            continue

        #https request for individual ad to dissect specific information
        try:
            singlePgContent = requests.get(ad_url, timeout=5, headers = getHeader).content
            print("Https Request Success: SINGLE AD:  {}".format(ad_url))
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
            print("ERROR: LINK FAILED - SKIPPED: {}".format(ad_url))
            continue

        single_page = BeautifulSoup(singlePgContent, "html.parser")
        
        try:
            attributes = single_page.find("div", {"class": "attributeListWrapper-2108313769"}) #both columns of attributes - holds 5 children nodes, we just need the first 2 columns
            print("retrieved attributes")
            columns = attributes.find_all("ul", {"class": "itemAttributeList-1090551278"}) #each is a column
            
            first_col = columns[0]  #year, make, model, trim
            second_col = columns[1] #body type, drivetrain, transmission, kilometers
            first_col_attributes = first_col.find_all("li", {"class": "itemAttributeWrapper-37588635"})
            second_col_attributes = second_col.find_all("li", {"class": "itemAttributeWrapper-37588635"})
            
        except (AttributeError):
            print("Could not retrieve attributes")
            continue

        for attribute_li in first_col_attributes:
            try:  #to check and see if dt (attribute name) exists, otherwise skip iteration -eg. carfax report has no attribute name
                label = attribute_li.find("dl", {"class": "itemAttribute-3080139557"}).find("dt", {"class": "attributeLabel-240934283"}).text
            except:
                continue
            try:
                if label == "Year":
                    carYear = attribute_li.find("dl", {"class": "itemAttribute-3080139557"}).find("dd", {"class": "attributeValue-2574930263"}).text
                    carDictionary["Year"] = int(carYear)
            except (AttributeError, ValueError):
                continue
            try:
                if label == "Make":
                    carMake = attribute_li.find("dl", {"class": "itemAttribute-3080139557"}).find("dd", {"class": "attributeValue-2574930263"}).text
                    carDictionary["Make"] = carMake
            except (AttributeError, ValueError):
                continue
            try:
                if label == "Model":
                    carModel = attribute_li.find("dl", {"class": "itemAttribute-3080139557"}).find("dd", {"class": "attributeValue-2574930263"}).text
                    carDictionary["Model"] = carModel
            except (AttributeError, ValueError):
                continue
            try:
                if label == "Trim":
                    carTrim = attribute_li.find("dl", {"class": "itemAttribute-3080139557"}).find("dd", {"class": "attributeValue-2574930263"}).text
                    carDictionary["Trim"] = carTrim
            except (AttributeError):
                carDictionary["Trim"] = None

        for attribute_li in second_col_attributes:
            try:  #to check and see if dt (attribute name) exists, otherwise skip iteration -eg. carfax report has no attribute name
                label = attribute_li.find("dl", {"class": "itemAttribute-3080139557"}).find("dt", {"class": "attributeLabel-240934283"}).text
            except:
                continue
            try:
                if label == "Body Type":
                    carBody = attribute_li.find("dl", {"class": "itemAttribute-3080139557"}).find("dd", {"class": "attributeValue-2574930263"}).text
                    carDictionary["Body"] = carBody
            except (AttributeError):
                carDictionary["Body"] = None
            try:
                if label == "Transmission":
                    carTrans = attribute_li.find("dl", {"class": "itemAttribute-3080139557"}).find("dd", {"class": "attributeValue-2574930263"}).text
                    carDictionary["Transmission"] = carTrans
            except (AttributeError):
                carDictionary["Transmission"] = None
            try:
                if label == "Kilometers":
                    carKM = int(attribute_li.find("dl", {"class": "itemAttribute-3080139557"}).find("dd", {"class": "attributeValue-2574930263"}).text.replace(',', ''))
                    carDictionary["Kilometers"] = carKM
            except (AttributeError, ValueError):
                carDictionary["Kilometers"] = None
            try:
                if label == "Drivetrain":
                    carDrivetrain = attribute_li.find("dl", {"class": "itemAttribute-3080139557"}).find("dd", {"class": "attributeValue-2574930263"}).text
                    carDictionary["Drivetrain"] = carDrivetrain
            except (AttributeError):
                carDictionary["Drivetrain"] = None

        print(carDictionary)

        listCars.append(carDictionary)
        
df = pandas.DataFrame(listCars)
df.to_csv('cars.csv')
print(df)
```

The output gives me:

40 Results on Page 2.
0 Results on Page 3.
Then prints the pandas dataframe of the list of dictionaries holding car listing data.

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs correctly on my computer like:

```
Https Request Success: FULL PAGE 2:  https://www.kijiji.ca/b-cars-trucks/ontario/used/page-2/c174l9004a49

40 Results on Page 2.
Https Request Success: SINGLE AD:  https://www.kijiji.ca/v-cars-trucks/chatham-kent/2009-bmw-328i-xdrive/1595980578
retrieved attributes
{'Ad ID': '1595980578', 'Ad URL': 'https://www.kijiji.ca/v-cars-trucks/chatham-kent/2009-bmw-328i-xdrive/1595980578', 'Price': 8000, 'Year': 2009, 'Make': 'BMW', 'Model': '3-Series', 'Trim': '328i xDrive', 'Body': 'Sedan', 'Drivetrain': 'All-wheel drive (AWD)', 'Transmission': 'Automatic', 'Kilometers': 191000}
Https Request Success: SINGLE AD:  https://www.kijiji.ca/v-cars-trucks/markham-york-region/2020-kia-sorento-2-4l-lx-awd-owner-lowks/m2613367
retrieved attributes
    Https Request Success: SINGLE AD:  https://www.kijiji.ca/v-cars-trucks/windsor-area-on/2018-hyundai-santa-fe-sport-luxury/m2567143
    retrieved attributes
    {'Ad ID': '2567143', 'Ad URL': 'https://www.kijiji.ca/v-cars-trucks/windsor-area-on/2018-hyundai-santa-fe-sport-luxury/m2567143', 'Price': 27225, 'Year': 2018, 'Make': 'Hyundai', 'Model': 'Santa Fe', 'Trim': 'Luxury', 'Drivetrain': 'All-wheel drive (AWD)', 'Transmission': 'Automatic', 'Kilometers': 57007}
   
.....
 
Https Request Success: FULL PAGE 3:  https://www.kijiji.ca/b-cars-trucks/ontario/used/page-3/c174l9004a49

40 Results on Page 3.
Https Request Success: SINGLE AD:  https://www.kijiji.ca/v-cars-trucks/windsor-area-on/2018-hyundai-santa-fe-sport-luxury/m2567143
retrieved attributes
{'Ad ID': '2567143', 'Ad URL': 'https://www.kijiji.ca/v-cars-trucks/windsor-area-on/2018-hyundai-santa-fe-sport-luxury/m2567143', 'Price': 27225, 'Year': 2018, 'Make': 'Hyundai', 'Model': 'Santa Fe', 'Trim': 'Luxury', 'Drivetrain': 'All-wheel drive (AWD)', 'Transmission': 'Automatic', 'Kilometers': 57007}
Https Request Success: SINGLE AD:  https://www.kijiji.ca/v-cars-trucks/windsor-area-on/2019-hyundai-tucson-preferred/m2451609
retrieved attributes
```

So I think your ip must be limited by the server.Because you have tried many times to request for the pages which get the server to do some `Rate Limit Strategies` on your ip. Maybe `changing your ip` will solve the problem.

Comment: I've tried changing my IP but I don't think that's resolved the issue unfortunately, I'm still getting 0 results on subsequent pages. It's odd because python requests is able to fetch the page successfully, but the server doesn't load any results.